# Merge multiple rows in variable type varchar

Tags: sql-server, temporary-tables

[image]

I Have temp table name `@Definition` which have 2 columns one for id and Field value I Have to take all rows in the field value as string in `@P_Output`

```
declare @P_Output varchar(500);
set @P_Output=(select case when (ISNumeric(FieldValue))=1 then convert(varchar(100),FieldValue) else FieldValue END from @Definition)
```

This give my an error :

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'You get an Error in line ' to data type int.

my table look like the picture 
and the required output 
needed to be :

```
P_Output=create table (id int not null identity(1,1).......
```

Comment: Please provide sample input data and the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to customize this example:

```
set nocount on
Declare @Definition table (ID int, FieldValue varchar(100))
DECLARE @P_Output varchar(max)

insert into @Definition (ID,FieldValue) values(1,'CREATE TABLE dbo.test')
insert into @Definition (ID,FieldValue) values(2,'(')
insert into @Definition (ID,FieldValue) values(3,'col1 int')
insert into @Definition (ID,FieldValue) values(4,')')

SELECT @P_Output = isnull(@P_Output + '', '') + FieldValue
from @Definition order by ID

print @P_Output
```